Finger placement problem
I can't use my pinky finger on my guitar like the rest of the fingers
It automatically gets rotated and it Mutes the string below it and also ruins the string that I'm holding with my pinky finger

How am I supposed to make it play normally without muting other strings and not ruin the one I'm playing?

i would suggest that you put all arched fingers on a table and slowly practice raising each finger in turn, very slowly. Really concentrate on your pinky, do it slowly and carefully and you will bring it into use.

The pinky finger is always the weakest when you start and it might need some practice to gain a bit more control over it.
Even simple chromatic exercises like going 1234 4321 starting from every string and every fret could be a good start. Then playing scales up and down just to get used to the fretboard.
But the best thing to do is to take a couple of lessons where teacher could work on your hand position and give you some exercises to correct bad habits early on. As your muscles grow in strenght you will be able to relax your hand a bit more and gain some more independence with each of the fingers.
Also it seems from the picture that the action on your guitar is quite high. This can be very discouraging for beginners so might be good idea to get the guitar setup correctly.

I don't have a mentor how do I set it up correctly

do you know make and model of your guitar?

Ya it's Ashton D20C NTM Cutaway Acoustic Guitar

It appears you're trying to use 1fpf - 1 finger per fret. There's absolutely no need to keep the other fingers all pressed onto the fingerboard while you press with the pinky. What's the point? None! So lift off, if only a small amount, any that impede proper use of that pinky, and you won't hear a scrap of difference in the sound produced, but it will be easier to fret with your pinky.
